# How can I run a site-site ipsec vpn behind a livebox?

Tags: ipsec, livebox

I've got a livebox at a site that needs to have an IPSec site-to-site vpn back into the head office. I can't figure out how to forward / bridge all ipsec (ESP, UDP 500) traffic to the vpn router that I have sitting behind the livebox LAN.

What is the correct way to pass through ipsec traffic (or all traffic if need be) from the livebox to the vpn router. The livebox can't be replaced with another device as unfortunately the site uses its voip functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good question for livebox support. Can't you get into the management console/webinterface?

Also, you should not put all your phone & email traffic in one basket (i.e. one internet connection): internet connections and routers are cheap these days.

There's another reason to seperate VOIP/SIP from VPN traffic: is your VPN tunnel going to be pumping many shared files or big attachments? When QOS (quality-of-service) is doing it's job, your computer users might find the going a bit slow when there's more than one VOIP/SIP conversation in progress.